# What is the most efficient and safest way to remove fingerprints from my Sony PRS-650 Touchscreen Reader?

Tags: sony-prs-650, touchscreen, maintenance, cleaning

I prefer to use a dry microfiber cloth to clean my touchscreen, but sometimes you have to scrub pretty hard to remove fingerprints. Is it safe to use a cleaner on the screen or should I use only water (or perhaps stick to dry cloth)?

Comment: Is there something special about that reader that the regular LCD cleaning methods won't work?

Comment: It's not a regular lcd screen, it has a thin layer for touch over an e-ink screen. I've heard conflicting advice about cleaners vs water only. I was hoping to get a better sense from a community of avid ereader users. I know there is at least one other user here that has the same device too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a little research, I came across [this post](http://www.lostinreaders.com/1102/news/how-to-clean-an-ebook-reader-display/). It details two different ways to clean eReader screens. One for E-Ink screens and one for LCD screens.

The Coles notes version for E-Ink screens:

- Use a dry cloth or dampen a cloth with water (microfiber preferred).
- Do not apply water directly.
- Carefully wipe screen with cloth and allow to dry before using.

The Coles notes version for LCD screens:

- Microfiber cloth
- LCD solution or mix (50-50) isopropyl alcohol and distilled water (not tap water!)
- Moisten cloth, wipe and dry before use.

So one recommends water and one recommends against water. PRS-650 is a touch screen, but is E-Ink display. So which way is better? It turns out the PRS-650 does not have a special layer on top of the E-Ink display like it's predecessor (it uses light sources firing over the surface to tell when there is something touching it, or just over it). More info [here](http://www.trustedreviews.com/sony-reader-prs-650-touch-edition_Peripheral_review_performance-and-touchscreen_Page-2#kKGR2mBm2WK2qrdi.99). So this leads me to believe it should be treated like an E-Ink display and cleaned accordingly.

Comment: I spent some time searching for specs on the screen. While doing so, I found the user guide, which actually says to clean the screen with a soft cloth (dry or slightly damp with water or a mild detergent... no alcohol or benzene). User guide: http://pdf.crse.com/manuals/4257661113.pdf

Comment: And thanks for the link about how the screen works. I want to look more into the technology about the light firing over the surface... sounds interesting.

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 7):

The first thing you should always do is look in your devices manual if there is a recommended way of cleaning (or doing anything else). It is probably the best way to avoid problems with your warranty (in case something goes wrong).

If you don't have your PRS-650 manual any more you can find it (googling `sony prs 650 support`)  [on-line](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=PRS650&LOC=3#/howtoTab) on the <kbd>Manual, Specs and Warranty</kbd> tab.
There you find the PDF version of the user manual. On page 114 it says:

> On cleaning
>
> - Clean the Reader with a soft cloth, such as a cleaning cloth for eyeglasses.
> - If the Reader becomes very dirty, clean it with a soft cloth slightly moistened with
>   water or a mild detergent solution.
> - Do not use any type of abrasive pad, scouring powder, or solvent, such as alcohol
>   or benzene, as it may mar the finish of the case.
> - Clean the headphone plug periodically.
> - Tapping or dragging on the touch screen using a dirty stylus may damage the surface. Wipe the stylus with a dry cloth when it gets dirty.